# Avoiding deadlocks due to queue overflow with multiprocessing.JoinableQueue

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Suppose we have a `multiprocessing.Pool` where worker threads share a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`, dequeuing work items and potentially enqueuing more work:

```py
def worker_main(queue):
    while True:
        work = queue.get()
        for new_work in process(work):
            queue.put(new_work)
        queue.task_done()
```

When the queue fills up, `queue.put()` will block. As long as there is at least one process reading from the queue with `queue.get()`, it will free up space in the queue to unblock the writers. But all of the processes could potentially block at `queue.put()` at the same time.

Is there a way to avoid getting jammed up like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how often `process(work)` creates more items, there may be no solution beside a queue of an infinite maximum size.

In short, your queue must be large enough to accomodate the entire backlog of work items that you can have at any time.

---

Since [queue is implemented with semaphores](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=joinablequeue#multiprocessing.Queue), there may indeed be [a hard size limit of `SEM_VALUE_MAX`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sem_open.2.html) which [in MacOS is 32767](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-201/bsd/sys/semaphore.h.auto.html). So you'll need to subclass that implementation or use `put(block=False)` and handle `queue.Full` (e.g. put excess items somewhere else) if that's not enough.

Alternatively, look at [one of the 3rd-party implementations of distributed work item queue for Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html).

Comment: I'm not specifying a maximum queue size but there seems to be an implicit one (on macOS).

Comment: I’m failing to see how handling Queue.Full could be done in the above example. I can’t lose work. I could set it aside for later, but the main process will terminate when the queue is drained.

Comment: I'll accept this because you hit upon the root cause, that `SEM_VALUE_MAX` on macOS is absurdly low, though unfortunately there is no good solution. (I moved to using Redis, which is going to be way slower than shared memory, alas.) Looking at xnu source, it seems as though there's no reason for this limit, so I've appealed to Apple to raise it.