# Python multiprocessing.pool's interaction with a class objective function and neuro-evolution

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch, genetic-algorithm

Warning, this is gonna be long since I want to be as specific as I can be.

---

Exact problem: This is a **multi-processing**  problem. I have ensured that my classes all behave as built/expected in previous experiments.

edit: said threading beforehand.

---

When I run toy example of my problem in a threaded environment, everything behaves; however, when I transition into my real problem, the code breaks. Specifically, I get a `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects` error. Full stack is at the bottom.

My threading needs here are bit different than the example I adapted my code from -- https://github.com/CMA-ES/pycma/issues/31. In this example we have one fitness function that can be independently called by each evaluation and none of the function calls can interact with each other. However, in my real problem we are trying to optimize neural network weights using a genetic algorithm. The GA will suggest potential weights and we need to evaluate these NN controller-weights in our environment. In a single threaded case, we can have just one environment where we evaluate the weights with a simple for-loop: `[nn.evaluate(weights) for weights in potential_candidates]`, find the best-performing individual, and use those weights in the next mutation round. However, we cannot simply have one simulation in a threaded environment.

So, instead of passing in a single function to evaluate I am passing in a list of function (one for each individual, where the environment is the same, but we have forked the processes so that the communication streams don't interact between individuals.)

One further thing of immediate note: 
I am using a build-for-parallel evaluation data-structure from neat

## from neat.parallel import ParallelEvaluator  # uses multiprocessing.Pool

Toy example code:

```
NPARAMS = nn.flat_init_weights.shape[0]    # make this a 1000-dimensional problem.
NPOPULATION = 5                            # use population size of 5.
MAX_ITERATION = 100                        # run each solver for 100 function calls.

import time
from neat.parallel import ParallelEvaluator  # uses multiprocessing.Pool
import cma

def fitness(x):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return sum(x**2)

# # serial evaluation of all solutions
# def serial_evals(X, f=fitness, args=()):
#     return [f(x, *args) for x in X]

# parallel evaluation of all solutions
def _evaluate2(self, weights, *args):
    """redefine evaluate without the dependencies on neat-internal data structures
    """
    jobs = []
    for i, w in enumerate(weights):
        jobs.append(self.pool.apply_async(self.eval_function[i], (w, ) + args))

    return [job.get() for job in jobs]

ParallelEvaluator.evaluate2 = _evaluate2
parallel_eval = ParallelEvaluator(12, [fitness]*NPOPULATION)

# time both
for eval_all in [parallel_eval.evaluate2]:
    es = cma.CMAEvolutionStrategy(NPARAMS * [1], 1, {'maxiter': MAX_ITERATION, 
                                                     'popsize': NPOPULATION})
    es.disp_annotation()
    while not es.stop():
        X = es.ask()
        es.tell(X, eval_all(X))
    es.disp()
```

## Necessary background:

When I switch from the toy example to my real code, the above fails.

My classes are:

```
LevelGenerator (simple GA class that implements mutate, etc)
GridGame (OpenAI wrapper; launches a Java server in which to run the simulation; 
          handles all communication between the Agent and the environment)
Agent    (neural-network class, has an evaluate fn which uses the NN to play a single rollout)
Objective (handles serializing/de-serializing weights: numpy <--> torch; launching the evaluate function)

# The classes get composed to get the necessary behavior:
env   = GridGame(Generator)
agent = NNAgent(env)                # NNAgent is a subclass of (Random) Agent)
obj   = PyTorchObjective(agent)

# My code normally all interacts like this in the single-threaded case:

def test_solver(solver): # Solver: CMA-ES, Differential Evolution, EvolutionStrategy, etc
    history = []
    for j in range(MAX_ITERATION):
        solutions = solver.ask() #2d-numpy array. (POPSIZE x NPARAMS)
        fitness_list = np.zeros(solver.popsize)
        for i in range(solver.popsize):
            fitness_list[i] = obj.function(solutions[i], len(solutions[i]))
        solver.tell(fitness_list)
        result = solver.result() # first element is the best solution, second element is the best fitness
        history.append(result[1])

        scores[j] = fitness_list

    return history, result
```

So, when I attempt to run:

```
NPARAMS = nn.flat_init_weights.shape[0]        
NPOPULATION = 5                                
MAX_ITERATION = 100                            

_x = NNAgent(GridGame(Generator))

gyms = [_x.mutate(0.0) for _ in range(NPOPULATION)]
objs = [PyTorchObjective(a) for a in gyms]

def evaluate(objective, weights):
    return objective.fun(weights, len(weights))

import time
from neat.parallel import ParallelEvaluator  # uses multiprocessing.Pool
import cma

def fitness(agent):
    return agent.evalute()

# # serial evaluation of all solutions
# def serial_evals(X, f=fitness, args=()):
#     return [f(x, *args) for x in X]

# parallel evaluation of all solutions
def _evaluate2(self, X, *args):
    """redefine evaluate without the dependencies on neat-internal data structures
    """
    jobs = []
    for i, x in enumerate(X):
        jobs.append(self.pool.apply_async(self.eval_function[i], (x, ) + args))

    return [job.get() for job in jobs]

ParallelEvaluator.evaluate2 = _evaluate2
parallel_eval = ParallelEvaluator(12, [obj.fun for obj in objs])
# obj.fun takes in the candidate weights, loads them into the NN, and then evaluates the NN in the environment.

# time both
for eval_all in [parallel_eval.evaluate2]:
    es = cma.CMAEvolutionStrategy(NPARAMS * [1], 1, {'maxiter': MAX_ITERATION, 
                                                     'popsize': NPOPULATION})
    es.disp_annotation()
    while not es.stop():
        X = es.ask()
        es.tell(X, eval_all(X, NPARAMS))
    es.disp()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-3e6b7bf6f83a> in <module>
      6     while not es.stop():
      7         X = es.ask()
----> 8         es.tell(X, eval_all(X, NPARAMS))
      9     es.disp()

<ipython-input-55-2182743d6306> in _evaluate2(self, X, *args)
     14         jobs.append(self.pool.apply_async(self.eval_function[i], (x, ) + args))
     15 
---> 16     return [job.get() for job in jobs]

<ipython-input-55-2182743d6306> in <listcomp>(.0)
     14         jobs.append(self.pool.apply_async(self.eval_function[i], (x, ) + args))
     15 
---> 16     return [job.get() for job in jobs]

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool, cache)
    429                         break
    430                     try:
--> 431                         put(task)
    432                     except Exception as e:
    433                         job, idx = task[:2]

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in send(self, obj)
    204         self._check_closed()
    205         self._check_writable()
--> 206         self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
    207 
    208     def recv_bytes(self, maxlength=None):

~/miniconda3/envs/thesis/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py in dumps(cls, obj, protocol)
     49     def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=None):
     50         buf = io.BytesIO()
---> 51         cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
     52         return buf.getbuffer()
     53 

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

I also read here that this might be being caused by the fact that this is a class function -- [TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144584/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects) -- so I created the global scoped fitness function `def fitness(agent): return agent.evalute()`, but that didn't work either.

I thought this error might be coming from the fact that originally, I had the evaluate function in the PyTorchObjective class as a lambda function, but when I changed that it still broke.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, and thanks for reading this giant wall of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using multiple threads. [You are using multiple processes.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

All arguments that you pass to `apply_async`, including the function itself, are serialized (pickled) under the hood and passed to a worker process via an IPC channel (read up [`multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) for details). So you cannot pass any entities that are tied to things that are by their nature process-local. This includes  most synchronization primitives since they have to use locks to do atomic operations.

Whenever this happens ([as many other questions on this error message show](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22can%27t%20pickle%20_thread.lock%20objects%22)), **you are likely trying to be too smart and passing to a parallelization framework an object that already has parallelization logic built in.**

---

If you want to create "multiple levels of parallelization" with such "parallelized object", you'll be better off either:

- using the parallelization mechanism of that object proper and not bother about multiple levels: you can't do more stuff at a time than you have cores anyway; or
- create and use these "parallelized objects" inside worker processes

  - but you are likely to hit `multiprocessing` limitations here since its worker processes are deliberately prohibited from spawning their own pools.

    - [You can let workers add extra items to the work queue but may hit `Queue` limitations as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876773/avoiding-deadlocks-due-to-queue-overflow-with-multiprocessing-joinablequeue/55876943#55876943)
  - so for such a scenario, [a more advanced 3rd-party distributed work queue solution](https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html) may be preferrable.

Comment: So, this is undoubtedly my lack of knowledge showing, but can you expand upon this statement: **you are likely trying to be too smart and passing to a parallelization framework an object that already has parallelization logic built in.**

How would my classes (I can provide the definitions) have parallelization logic built in? I definitely didn't add it.

Comment: @aadharna I thought that it's the `PyTorch` object that is "parellelized" (PyTorch does have a parallel processing framework but it turns out, it's optional). But looking at the stacktrace, you are trying to pass `job` to a subprocess. I don't know what that it is supposed to do and why you are hacking into `ParallelEvaluator`. [Looking at its docs](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/parallel.html), `evaluate2` is not supposed to be overridden. So it looks like the immediate error is you are trying to pass an internal object from `multiprocessing` itself to another process.

Comment: Googling ""PyTorch" parallel processing", it looks like that library prefers to offload stuff to GPUs instead of other processes. Which seems to make multiple processes irrelevant in the common case (since they would all use the same GPU). But it does have [its own specialized version of `multiprocessing`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html) so I guess it has some use and you should look there for pointers when and how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: The thought behind using `ParallelEvalutor` was: 1) It's the simple example that NikoHansen used here when he first went about adding parallelism to pycma: https://github.com/CMA-ES/pycma/issues/31 2) As you pointed out in the docs link, the class is very lightweight 3) it seemed simple to bypass the neat functionality built into `ParallelEvalutor.evaluate` and add my own evaluate function. It worked for the simple case (first code block) where I have a fitness fn in global scope.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that I am **not** using PyTorch for it's auto-diff  (back-propagation) functionality, therefore moving data to the GPU and PyTorch's version of multiprocessing is not helpful.

I am using PyTorch to easily define the NN and run inference (forward-propagation).

Comment: @aadharna Well, debugging time then. Check what exactly you are passing to `apply_async` and which of that is not picklable.

Comment: @aadharna I've got a hunch that you don't need `ParallelEvaluator` at all -- since you are overriding the bulk of its functionality anyway, and in a way that duplicates `Pool.map`. Alternatively, subclassing it and overriding `evaluate` seems a cleaner solution than hacking, too.

Comment: You're right. It would be cleaner to subclass it! I shall investigate which of my things are not picklable and implement the subclassing tomorrow. Thanks for the leads.